# How to find cause of server hanging while having only 3 seconds of access

Tags: fail2ban, debian-buster, hangs

Remote debian buster server, so can't go to console.

Yesterday it worked properly, today it has stopped responding. I can reboot it remotely, so after reboot I can reconnect, but I can only run short command like top and I lose the connection. On top, I found that 100% is clamd, but when I tried to `/etc/init.d/clamd-daemon sto` I lost the connection before typing last the letter. So I copied it next time, but it doesn't help. I wonder which logs should I try to get (via scp) for better diagnosis....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fail2ban has add my address into blacklist, and 3 seconds fail2ban needs to load the list....

Hope somebody helps....

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is to go rescue mode and turn off programs which I saw it top during 3 seconds of access.. And when it goes back to work - one of programs is a bad guy... So one after one...

Answer (score 0):

You should check the output from `sudo dmesg -T`